# SQL Injection Protection - Where and When

Tags: php, sql-server, .htaccess, mysqli, sql-injection

I'm building a website which uses information passed through a URL to pick out information from a database table, but it was brought to my attention that doing this may cause a SQL Injection. As I thought this was only an issue where you were **inserting** information into a database, I'm a bit confused as to when, how and where you should protect your code.

Currently I have a url which looks like:

```
www.website.com/article.php?title=title&id=1
```

Which is shortened in htaccess to `www.website.com/article/title/1`

In my article.php page I then have:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){$url_id = $_GET["id"];}else{
header("Location: $site_url");
exit();
};
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["title"])){$url_title = $_GET["title"];}else{
header("Location: $site_url");
exit();
};
?>
<?php
$article_sql = "SELECT ...
```

I currently use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL Injection threats, but I'm unsure where to use it here. I'm guessing that adding...

```
...
<?php
if(isset($_GET["title"])){$url_title = $_GET["title"];}else{
header("Location: $site_url");
exit();
};
?>
<?php
$url_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($url_id); // ADDED
$url_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($url_title); // ADDED
?>
<?php
$article_sql = "SELECT 
...
```

Should do the trick, but is this correct?

Comment: Everything what you need is in this thread.

Comment: Just for your info, mysqli_real_escape_string has absolutely nothing to do with SQL injections.

Comment: @YourCommonSense So why have I been told on so many occasions that it is a solution to Injection threats?

Comment: http://www.sqlinjection.net/advanced/php/mysql-real-escape-string/ ???

Comment: And probably this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Okay @S.I., but is there a solution to the code I provided? I'd like to get this sorted without having to change my coding style too much

Comment: In my opinion you'll not be safe until you start to use prepared statements. Just don't inject directly the variable in the query.

Comment: @S.I. Any suggestions on how I can do it indirectly? I mean passing variables through a URL is pretty standard practice. How do sites that don't use Prepared statements cope with this issue?

Comment: *"why have I been told on so many occasions?"* - because there are too many idiots around? Just for clarity, the only trusting source is a manual page and there is not a single mention of whatever injection in the documentation text.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well it seems there are a lot of idiots here on the Stack then. And in that case, is any of the information posted here of any use to anyone?

Comment: All the suggestions has been posted in the very first comment half a hour ago. Do you *really* think you are the very first person with such a question here?

Comment: Seems you're the least helpful person here anyway @YourCommonSense

Comment: *"it seems there are a lot of idiots here on the Stack then"* - unfortunately, yes. *"is any of the information posted here of any use to anyone"* - in such a vague form - yes, of course. Some information is surely of some use for someone. But you cannot blindly trust to everything posted here as it is posted by fellow users like you.

Comment: I am just the least *servile* person here, which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You already use `mysqli_` so take advantage of it. Here is simple example based on code you provide:

```
<?php
 // $mysqli is the connection
$article_sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE url_id = ? AND url_title = ?");

$article_sql->bind_param("is", $url_id, $url_title);
$article_sql->execute();

$result = $article_sql->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  foreach ($row as $r) {
    print "$r ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely going to look into using this code. Just as a side question - Is it true that for an injection attack to `Drop` one of your tables, it must know the name of the table? If so, wouldn't it be a good solution to just give the table an obscure name?

Comment: Well, yes... attacker must know what he attack :) But he must find it with injection which you will prevent using this techniques. Check this [cheet sheet](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Seems the attackers can find a way around everything, lol. As I'm sure they are unfortunately bound to do again, even making prepared statements unsafe in the future :-( - Is there a way to prevent them from Listing Tables and Databases using a universal PHP code that can be placed in a single `include` file?

Comment: Well you can restrict user what permission to have over mysql database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html . And restrict the user to use only certain tables.

Comment: Well I've added myself as a user to the database in CPanel, and set permissions, but would this prevent a URL based attack. I was wondering if... As I know my url's will never use a special character, if I could set it so that if a special char existed in any url, I could use a PHP script to automatically redirect to another page to prevent the attacking url from even loading up the targeted page?

Comment: Everything coming from user side should be triple check, sanitized, escaped, prepared.. etc.. Never trust users :)

Comment: What I mean is, nothing legitimate would ever contain a special character, because it's all text titles and id numbers, so if something with a `@` or `"` came through a URL it would almost definitely be something suspicious. So therefore can a script be made to capture the url of every page, and redirect back out if a special character exists?

Comment: Should be possible to include such a script on each page yes.

Comment: And would that be a viable solution in preventing a possible SQL injection?

Comment: I'm not hundred percent sure but If you use modern techniques you won't be worried about it.

Comment: I'll look into using the code you provided, but as the site is live and has content on there already, I'm obviously reluctant to mess around too much with the coding. Thanks again S.I.

Comment: You can make some test environment on localhost or something. And start slowly to change first critical pages i.e. where user make inputs.